# Error al compilar SciPy para ARM

Tags: python, embebido, scipy, arm, compilación-cruzada

Estoy intentando compilar el paquete de Python, SciPy para instalarlo en una placa en la que no cuento con un compilador cruzado; para ello estoy realizando la compilación en una Beaglebone Black.

He instalado el paquete Numpy mediante el comando`sudo pip install numpy`, además tambien he intalado otros paquetes y librerias adicionales requeridas por SciPy (Cython, OpenBlas, Lapack, GFortran). Estoy empleando la version 3.6 de Python.

He intentado compilar SciPy de tres maneras, más o menos similares:

1. En primer lugar he intentado generar el archivo `.whl` para así pasarlo a la otra placa y poder instalarlo directamente, para generar dicho archivo he introducido el comando `sudo pip wheel scipy==0.18.1`, tras un rato da un error y finaliza. El mensaje de error es el siguiente.

   ```
       arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus) Please Submit a full bug report, with preprocessed source if appropiate.
   See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
   error: Command "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wno-unused-result _wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g 
   -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D_STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iscipy/sparse/sparsetools 
   -I/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m
   -c scipy/sparse/sparse/tools/csr.cxx -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.6/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.o
   -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.6/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.o.d" failed with exit status 4
   ```
2. La segunda forma en la que lo he intentado, ha sido descargando los fuentes de SciPy y he introducido el comando `sudo python setup.py dbist_wheel` pero al igual que en el caso anterior, tras un rato da el mismo error y finaliza.
3. Por último he intentado seguir las instrucciones de compilación e instalación que vienen en [la documentación de SciPy](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/linux.html#generic-instructions) con los mismos resultados.

He compilado otros paquetes, incluido el propio Numpy; de la misma manera para posteriormente instalarlo en la otra placa, para este paquete ¿necesito hacer algo más? ¿Por qué da este error? ¿Puedo descargar el `.whl` para ARM en alguna parte?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

El problema estaba en la memoria RAM, la **beaglebone** solo dispone de 512MB y llegado cierto punto de la compilación se superaba con creces esa cifra.

He creado una memoria RAM virtual de 1 GB para disponer en total de 1'5GB y la compilación ha concluido sin problemas. La compilación llegaba a consumir algo más de 1 GB.